# Azure IoTHub.EnqueuedTime Invalid on ASA Job

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub

I am pushing data from IoT Hub with an ASA job.  I would really like to use the IoTHub.EnqueuedTime to determine latency for messages.  Unfortunately, the attribute is always:

0001-01-01T00:00:00.0000000

Here is the query:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/37b22.png)

Any ideas on how I can get the actual date/time that the message was received by IoT Hub?

Thanks,

Todd

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. Would you mind showing your related code?

Comment: I am just pulling from the IoT Hub using the following syntax:  IoTHub.EnqueuedTime is the field.  I am not doing any windowing, etc.  Very straight-forward.  The only date I am seeing is the 0001-01-01T00:00:00:000000.

Comment: Is anyone else trying to utilize the IoTHub.EnqueuedTime via Stream Analytics?  If yes, are you seeing an actual date/time?

Answer (score 0):

EnqueuedTime is a property that is stamped by IoTHub only when it receives a command destined for a Device. A device will receive the EnqueuedTime property when it receives a command.

This property is not supported on the telemetry path when a Device sends a telemetry message to IoTHub.